# Packet Tracer Webcam

Tags: networking, network-programming

When I try to connect the cable with the webcam, it says the cable cannot be connected to that port.
Can anyone help me with this, please
[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

So I met the same issue that you got when following the lab tutorial and in order to resolve it, you need to :

1. left-click on the webcam
   -->  it will open its setting windows
2. click the "Advanced" button
   --> the "I/O Config" tab will appear
3. under "I/O Config" tab you will need to change the value of the field "Network Adapter" and select one type of adapter which can connect to the router by ethernet for example the one ending with "CFE" like in here attached picture

[image: screenshot of "I/O Config" tab]

Comment: Thank you very much. This worked for me. But Cisco should have educated us about this in the video tutorial or elsewhere. Anyway, thanks